# Where is Sun's JDK located on the filesystem?

Tags: java, jdk

I installed Sun's JDK and i can't locate it.

The one located at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/` is only JRE, where is JDK?

Answer (score 4):

From a terminal,
Confirm if the package is installed using.

```
sudo dpkg -l|grep -i sun-java6-jdk
```

List all the files installed by the package using

```
sudo dpkg -L  sun-java6-jdk
```

The listing of all files will help you to locate where directories/files installed by Ubuntu.

Comment: Only one that truly answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

Install `sun-java6-sdk` and it'll install the SDK.  The SDK and the JRE are separate packages.

Comment: i installed it.

Comment: All you'd need to worry about is having it installed.  Eclipse and other IDEs will be able to detect the software.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
update-alternatives --display java
```

This will list all java packages installed in your system.

Sample output:

```
java - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java - priority 63
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java'.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out what is the default on your system you could do it like this.

```
ls -ltr /etc/alternatives/javac
```

It will list a symbolic link pointing to the default jdk of your system.

On my system the default is located at '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk'. There is also an alternative jdk installed at '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun'.

If there aren't any you will need to install the package 'sun-java6-jdk' as pointed out in some other post.

Answer (score 0):

Mine in in  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/`

You can check yours via synaptic, select sun-java6-jdk, Properties